# I want to retrieve pdf file display on web browser

Tags: php, file, pdf

I had created database with 2 fields filename and path 
filename as dwm.pdf and path as C:\xampp\htdocs\p1\testing.
I just want to display pdf file on link click with the help of path store in database.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","billa","pdf_trial") or die
("Couldn't connect");
echo "Connected";
$q = "SELECT path FROM pdffiles WHERE filename =dwm"
$r = mysqli_query($q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

?>
```

i want to display pdf file on web by accessing path which i has store in mysql.
how i can do this

Comment: Good, and what have tried?

Comment: If you want you need to write PHP code.

Comment: i'm new to php don't know how to do it,I just want a simple approach to retrieve and display pdf via path that is store in database.correct me if im wrong

Comment: You need to provice a [mcve] in order for us to know exactly what you want. In general you should learn [ask], that will help you get good answers.

Comment: i have updated my concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the path which was retrieved from the database with `$row['path']` and then output the pdf file with `readfile()`:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","billa","pdf_trial") or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
$q = "SELECT path FROM pdffiles WHERE filename = 'dwm'"
$r = mysqli_query($q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile($row['path']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an Iframe to link your pdf

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://path.com/to/your/pdf.pdf&embedded=true" 
style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: how can i do this with mysql

Comment: get the data by select query and echo the path after making the file url in src field of Iframe.